# How to set equal thickness for all programatically added vertical lines in android

Tags: android

I am programmatically adding table rows , horizontal lines and vertical lines. When I add vertical lines except one line all other lines are displayed with high thickness.  Could anyone help solving this.

[image: enter image description here]]

```
for (int j=0; j<arr.length(); j++){
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(j);
View horizLine = new View(this.land);
horizLine.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
horizLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
tableLayout.addView(horizLine);
TableRow tbrowData = new TableRow(this.land);
tableLayout.addView(tbrowData);

for(int k=0; k< hdr.size(); k++) {

    View vrtlview = new View(this.land);
    vrtlview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    vrtlview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
    tbrowData.addView(vrtlview);

    TextView txtVData = new TextView(this.land);
    txtVData.setText(jObj.getString(hdr.get(k)) + "    ");
    tbrowData.addView(txtVData);
}

// Vertical line at right end
View vrtlview = new View(this.land);
vrtlview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
vrtlview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
tbrowData.addView(vrtlview);

//Horizantal line at bottom 
View horizLineEnd = new View(this.land);
horizLineEnd.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
horizLineEnd.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
tableLayout.addView(horizLineEnd);
```

Comment: Dou you have android:stretchColumns property set in your xml file or wherever you have created the TableLayout?

Comment: I donot have android:stretchColumns property in xml file .